# Should the Mighty Mjölnir have allowed me to reopen this question?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen

A few minutes ago, my [newly acquired superpowers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) have allowed me to reopen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662301/difference-between-get-and-eq-in-jquery) with a single binding vote.

> *Disclaimer: Before voting, I took care to select a question that I
>   believe could be reopened without causing much harm to the community.
>   Feel free to close it again if you disagree.*

I have a couple of concerns about that, and I would like to share them with you.

### Posteriority

The question was closed quite a while ago, way before owners of gold badges gained binding votes. Accordingly, it was closed by five users. Should a single user really be able to reopen it now?

In most of the countries running on principles other than *le fait du Prince*, laws cannot be retroactive, for good reason. I wonder if the same standards should not apply here, and if reopen votes cast on questions closed before our new powers came into effect should remain non-binding.

### Conflict of Interest

I have an answer under that question. That can make me biased when determining whether or not it should be reopened. Until now, non-binding votes meant that four other users (or a moderator) would have to agree with me before the question could be reopened. Now I can do that quietly on my own.

I'm personally not comfortable with this situation, and I believe reopen votes should remain non-binding when cast by gold badge owners who have answered the question (even if their answer was subsequently deleted).

What is your opinion on this? Do you think binding reopen votes should be a little more limited, as I do?

Comment: The "Possible Duplicate" banner staying on the top even though it's open looks like a bug, BTW.

Comment: Being retroactive would mean all the close/reopen votes you had previously cast immediately become binding (assuming they were still penfing). By your same argument, moderators should only have super-powers on questions posted after they were elected. You have the power *now* and you are making the decision *now*. It's a new action and thus cannot be retroactive.

Comment: @Wooble - The question was closed when the possible duplicate was edited into the question itself. Reopening doesn't remove that text.

Comment: @animuson, point taken. Indeed, retroactivity is probably not the right word here. I'll change it if I find something better. Thanks for answering my first concern :)

Comment: I do think that the user having an answer on the question is definitely something we should consider. I know a couple users that like to vote to reopen things *solely* for that reason, and not because they should actually be reopened.

Comment: Can't we just file that under "abuse", @animuson? "Cutting your uncle's brake lines" and "cutting your uncle's brake lines so that you'll inherit his cashmere sweater collection" are both "murder".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't see any distinction between being able to unilaterally reopen questions that were closed by someone else with a gold badge, being closed today with 5 votes from the community, and being closed by 5 votes from the community years ago.

Either the question is really a duplicate or it's not, and you've earned the right to make that call by your long history of contributions in the tag.

I think a gold badge holder is more qualified to make the determination of whether a post is a "real" duplicate than a diamond mod without subject expertise or 5 voters who could have just been going along with a bandwagon VtC.

Answer (score 5):

Why shouldn't you be able to cast a binding reopen vote?

Adding code to check to see if the question was closed with a binding "gold badge" vote would make extra work for the developers and be something else in the system to go wrong and have to be maintained.

If you can be trusted to close a duplicate question with a binding vote you can be trusted to reopen one incorrectly closed.

As to whether it's a conflict of interest because you answered the question - if you want to argue that then you should be arguing for the system to prevent *anyone* who's answered from voting to reopen (and I'm not suggesting that).

Comment: Even if I answered it? Don't you think this has potential for abuse?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - If that's the case then the system should prevent *anyone* who's answered from voting to reopen (and I'm not suggesting that).

Comment: If the votes were all binding, I agree the system should do that. Requiring a consensus of several voters alleviated that problem before IMHO.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi How exactly do you think it advantages you to reopen the question if you've answered it already? What do you think the conflict of interest is?

Comment: @slugster, let's consider a worst-case situation. A low-quality, duplicate question is posted with a tag I have a gold badge for. I decide to answer the question instead of closing it. Other users do the right thing and vote to close it as a duplicate. This situation does not suit me, because I want the rep and answers to closed questions are not viewed much. Therefore, I single-handedly reopen it for my own interest and to the detriment of the community's. I can even close the other question as a duplicate of the one I answered if it has similar tags.