# Reopen-hammering my own question

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

A question of mine was closed as a duplicate by five independent (non-Gold-badge) users. I disagreed and reopened it using my dupe hammer. (Actually, this was an accident -- I wanted to vote for reopening and forgot that I got the relevant Gold badge a few weeks ago.)

Should I feel bad about using the hammer for my own questions and maybe reclose my question (which seems wrong since I still disagree with that decision), or is that how the system is supposed to work?

Comment: Well, that's not going to impress the five users that made the effort to get it closed.  Not so sure this was the intention of the hammer, maybe you ought to use the [bug] tag instead.

Comment: Related: [Should the Mighty Mjölnir have allowed me to reopen this question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254989/should-the-mighty-mj%C3%B6lnir-have-allowed-me-to-reopen-this-question?rq=1)

Comment: As a close voter on the receiving end of that particular hammer, I'd say: Yes, you should feel bad. :-P

Comment: @Wormbo: Well, I did (a bit), which is why I asked the meta question here. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I I feel the dupe hammer should work for reopening, but I *do* think the dupe hammer should not work on your own questions at all. It's the kind of power that is too easy to abuse.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in this Q&A: [**Should the Mighty Mjölnir have allowed me to reopen this question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254989/should-the-mighty-mj%C3%B6lnir-have-allowed-me-to-reopen-this-question?lq=1)

> Either the question is really a duplicate or it's not, and you've earned the right to make that call by your long history of contributions in the tag.

So, it's assumed that your re-opening of the question is valid.

**That said**, the question was, *apparently*, unclear enough  that 5 other users thought it was a duplicate and voted accordingly.

So you should follow the instructions that appear when a question is marked as a duplicate and edit the question to explain **why** it's not a duplicate and explain the differences.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've rewritten and restructured my question based on the comments received to (hopefully) make it more obvious why the proposed duplicate does not answer it.

Comment: Ah - so the close vote worked as intended, and the re-open hammer worked as intended, and all's well that ends well. Beer and cookies all 'round! :-)

Answer (score 18):

Theory and practicality often collide in interesting ways :)

In *theory*, you've got not only a good breadth of knowledge *of* the tag, but also a pretty good breadth of knowledge of the questions we have *within* the tag. As such, it shouldn't really matter if it's your question or not. Hoooold the down-votes, I said *in theory*.

Practically speaking, it's probably best to bring it up here on meta, so that anyone that participated in marking the question as a duplicate has a say. Forgot that you had the ability? No big deal - you're still bringing it up here - and the merits of the closing can be talked about. To that, it's probably a good idea to ask another question about the closing itself, outside from the meta discussion surrounding use of the hammer.

As far as the functionality goes - I don't want to prevent the behavior outright because there are so many low-volume tags where any discussion would just result in crickets. I don't want to complicate it by defining what low-volume means and only allowing it in those situations because that just starts to look like spaghetti.

If it *really* becomes a problem, I'm happy to revisit it, but I don't think a change in software is what's needed at this point; all that's needed for now is clarification of the process, which is what you've accomplished here :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've rewritten the question as suggested by Paulie_D, and if there's still a strong community opinion that it's a duplicate, I'll bring the specific question up on meta.